# Looking for code to benchmark C lib string and memory functions

Tags: benchmarking, memcpy, strcmp, memset, strcpy

I'm looking for existing code I can use to benchmark C lib memory and string functions like memcpy, memset, strcpy, strcmp, etc. I've done a google search and there are several hits for people who have done such benchmarking but everybody seems to write their own code or they don't mention what they used?

There is cachebench which has test for memset and memcpy. I'm wonder if there are any other popular benchmark suites with such tests? I don't want to reinvent the wheel here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu.org provides a [program](http://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/bench-string.html#bench-string) which benchmarks:

- strcpy
- strcat
- strlen
- strcmp
- strrchr
- strstr